# SelectNodes with Filter

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectnodes

Here is my xml:

```
<Instrument RecordCount="3" >
    <Department id = 18384, Sequence=1>
    <InstrumentData StatusCode="1" RoleType="ED" Style="X" DataOther='Data'>
</Department>
<Department id = 18465, Sequence=2>
     <InstrumentData StatusCode="2" RoleType="CD" Style="S" DataOther='Data'>
</Department>
<Department id = 16473, Sequence=3>
    <InstrumentData StatusCode="1" RoleType="CD" Style="T" DataOther='Data'>
</Department>
 </Instrument>
```

I want @Status attribute ='1' or '2' and not @RoleType='E' and 'F' and @Style ='S' and 'T' for each node.

I have the following statement, but it does not bring back the correct results.

`XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes(@"//Department[InstrumentData/@Status='1'
                   or Department[InstrumentData/@Status='1'
                   and not (Department[InstrumentData/@RoleType='E'
                          or Department[InstrumentData/@RoleType='F')
                   and (Department[InstrumentData/@Style='S'
                          or Department[InstrumentData/@Style='T')
                     ]", manager);`

Or do I first need to get the first condition, then build xml doc, then get next condition.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but this is an absolute mess. Your xml is not well formed. And your xpath expression has lot of missing brackets.

Comment: But that's my question, can I string the conditions as above after each other to get the desired result?

Comment: updated xml:<Instrument RecordCount="3" >
<Department id = "18384"  Sequence="1">
    <InstrumentData StatusCode="1" RoleType="ED" Style="X" DataOther="Data"/>
</Department>
<Department id = "18465"  Sequence="2">
     <InstrumentData StatusCode="2" RoleType="CD" Style="S" DataOther="Data"/>
</Department>
<Department id = "16473" Sequence="3">
    <InstrumentData StatusCode="1" RoleType="CD" Style="T" DataOther="Data"/>
</Department>
</Instrument>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it to work:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList0 = root.SelectNodes(@"//ns1:Department[(ns1:InstrumentData/@StatusCode='1'
                                                                or ns1:InstrumentData/@StatusCode='2')
                                                                 and not (ns1:InstrumentData/@RoleType='ED' 
                                                                    or ns1:InstrumentData/@RoleType='FD') 
                                                                and (ns1:InstrumentData/@Style='S' 
                                                                     or ns1:InstrumentData/@Style='T') ]", manager);
```

Thanks for the feedback and prompt responses and input!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem to have complex conditions in xpaht expressions.
But your example can not work because of some mistakes.
* Some brackets (`]`) are missing
* There is no Status attribute in your example xml.
* You cant use "or" to put together a note list.

Example:
If you try to get Departments with `InstrumentData/@StatusCode = 2` and  Departments with `InstrumentData/@Style= T`.

**The following will not work:**

```
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//Department[InstrumentData/@StatusCode='2'] or //Department[InstrumentData/@Style='T' ]");
```

But you can do either:

```
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//Department[InstrumentData/@StatusCode='2'] | //Department[InstrumentData/@Style='T' ]");
```

Or (in my view better):

```
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//Department[InstrumentData/@StatusCode='2' or InstrumentData/@Style='T' ]");
```

Comment: If this was what you are looking for, mark my answer  or your own as accepted. (Than other people know this issue is solved)